# Allow open and print pdf file without asking a password but prevent editing content of the file using PDFTK?

Tags: 22.04, pdftk

I'm using pdftk to manage pdf files on a website , now what I'd like to know if is it possible to allow open and print pdf files **without asking a password** but prevent editing content of file using PDFTK.

In fact , there are many online pdf editors and the client ask me to prevent editing his pdf files on those editors.

What I find on the documentation is always passord is needed like so :

```
pdftk a.pdf output b.pdf owner_pw 123 user_pw 111
```

Comment: So the user will own a copy of the PDF, downloaded, but won't be able to edit *their own copy* of the PDF? That isn't really possible.

Comment: Unless you want `DRM` for PDFs, try looking that up and see if it works for you. It might be possible, but it's most likely somewhat complicated, and most methods can be worked around.

Comment: I think the fast solution is to convert pdf to jpeg then convert the jpeg to pdf with "ImageMagick"